# How to properly structure a database in Mongoose/MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Up until now I've been using relational DB, and I'm having a hard time adjusting my way of thinking about database design now that I've switched over to MongoDB (using Mongoose with Express).

I often find myself going "*Well why can't I just put a id there to refer to?... etc*" and just defaulting back to thinking in terms of a relational DB.

I understand that the point of MongoDB is to nest things like a JSON structure. But I find that if I use that approach, I can technically nest my entire app in one collection. But somehow I don't feel that this is the right approach... Here's an simple example layout of my application:

```
{
  company: {
    collections: [{
      createdBy,
      documents: [{
        text,
        createdBy
      }],
      title
    }],
    templates: [{
      text,
      createdBy,
      placeholders
    }],
    users: [{
      email,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      password
    }]
  }
}
```

A company will have many users, and each user can create templates, users can also create collections (like folders that contain documents), which will have many documents, but documents don't have to belong to a collection. Documents are created from existing templates (but they don't need to have any relation in the DB).

- **Company** - has many templates, documents, collections and users.
- **User** - belongs to company, has many documents, collections, and templates
- **Collection** - belongs to user and company, has many documents
- **Document** - belongs to user, company, and collection
- **Template** - belongs to user and company

I feel like I can technically make one collection called `company` and just nest everything else as sub-docs under it. Or the way I'm used to is just to add id refs to everything, and make everything it's own separate collection.

Both ways don't seem a bit iffy... Could someone please use my example and show me how they would properly design a database in MongoDB, and explain why they chose to do it the way they did?

This would **tremendously** help me better understand how to approach designing database schemas in Mongo.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example, let's look at the `users` of a `company`.

There are multiple ways to set this up.

- As a field in a `company` document (as you did);
- In a separate collection.

If you choose the second option, you will need to link users to companies. You can do this in multiple ways via foreign keys:

- Add an array of `user` ids in each `company` document;
- Add an array of `company` ids in each `user` document;
- Both of the above.

Alternatively, you could duplicate some or all of the user data in the `users` field of the `company` collection. In your definition, you have 4 fields of each user in the `company` collection; the `users` collection could have additional information about each user, for example an account number or a home address.

Now, the big question is: which option should you choose?

That mainly depends on the queries/searches you will expect to be running. Some examples:

If you want to show a page for a company with a list of all users of that company, having the relevant user information inside the company collection means you only need 1 query to find all information to show this page.

If you want to make it possible for users to log in somehow, it would make sense to have a separate `users` collection.

If users can be in multiple companies, and you want to be able to show the list of companies that a user belongs to on the user's page, you could use the `companies` array in the `users` collection.

Following these guidelines will probably help you:

- MongoDB is not good at JOINs.
- Data duplication is acceptable.

You can find more guidance [on the mongodb blog](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1).